# yii2 password rules pattern

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

you can at yii2 in the Model Rules enter patterns in passwords ? Tips for a rule that at least one uppercase character and at least one number ? Thanks so much

**Rules**

```html
['password', 'pattern' => '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20}'],
```

Comment: rule array misses one argument, it should be `['password', 'match','pattern' => '..']`, I know it's just a typo but for those who copy past like me it will be confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your case probably does not work because for some reason Yii2 does not recognize `\d` or `\p` so you have to write this part manually or find a way around.

I have tested this one:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

This means it will require at least one upper-case letter and at least one digit (lower-case letters are not necessary).